# asp net core kestrel high cpu usage

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cpu-usage, .net-5, kestrel

I Have some Web Api Applications in .Net5 + Kestrel, and I Want to test maximum request that can handles.
When I increase the number of requests from low to high (for example, from 10 simultaneous requests to 50 and then 100 and finally 500) the programs have no problem and can Answer 500 requests async in 5 seconds.
But when after a while (for example 10 minutes) I send another 500 requests to the server again, the CPU consumption reaches 100% and the programs do not respond and I have to restart the programs to solve the response problem.

How should I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

After debugging the program and using the dotTrace program, I realized that when I wanted to create an httpConnection within the services, I would dispose of that value after using it, and when the amount of requests on the server increased, the action of creating and eliminating of httpConnecton , put a lot of overhead on the server.

I hope it helps somebody

I know the solution for these kind of problems is to use IHttpClientFactory.
but because I use EurekaServiceDiscovery and I should make a DiscoveryHttpClientHandler and pass it to HttpClient Constructor.I cant do such a thing. so what is the solution